# Why is the sine of x squared equivalent to sine squared of x?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the sine of x squared equivalent to sine squared of x?

How can we verify this or what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: You mean why is $(\sin(x))^2 = \sin^2(x)$?  That's just what the notation means.

Comment: The expression "sine of x squared" might mean (sine of x) squared, or sine of (x squared). These are completely different. Which do you mean?

Comment: But the square in $\sin^2(x)$ is **not** what the square of function sometimes means: $f^2(x) = (f\circ f)(x) = f(f(x))$. Is that the confusion?

Comment: I meant why the (sin(x)^2=sin^2(x). Is it because it's just defined that way?

Comment: It's bad notation, but it's very entrenched, so everyone has to stumble over it when they first see it.

Comment: It's just a notational convention.  It doesn't mean that two different expressions, each with its own definition, are equal; rather, it's a convention that says "We can write this thing in this other format if we want to".

Comment: @peterwhy: For the curious, [here's what the other $\sin^2$ function looks like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28sin%28x%29%29).